# type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

After running **dart migrate** & applying null safety, that error popped up at my code and I think that's the error causing code block.

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, cons) {
  return GestureDetector(
    child: new Stack(
      children: <Widget?>[
        // list of different widgets 
        .
        .
        .
      ].where((child) => child != null).toList(growable: true) as List<Widget>,
    ),
  );
),
```

The error message says:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
type 'List<Widget?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>' in type cast

The relevant error-causing widget was
LayoutBuilder
package:projectName/…/components/fileName.dart:182
```

If anyone encountered this issue, how it can be solved?

Comment: simply delete the ?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. @Irsvmb

Comment: The children widgets of the stack goes red when I remove the " ? " 
Error message is: 
`the element type 'container?' can't be assigned to list type 'Widget'. **for example**
@lrsvmb

Comment: Due to null safety restrictions removing all of them would cause another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `as` to cast `List<T?>` to `List<T>` because they are not directly related types; you would need to cast the *elements* instead, using [`List<Widget>.from()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.from.html) or [`Iterable.cast<Widget>()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html).

See [Dart convert List<String?> to List nnbd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66896648/) for how to remove `null` elements from a `List<T?>` *and* get a `List<T>` result (and thus avoiding the need to cast later).

Answer (score 4):

Although there are different ways to solve it as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66896866/6618622) by [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) but the recommended one is to use [`whereType`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-wheretype-to-filter-a-collection-by-type). For example:

```dart
List<Widget?> nullableWidgets = [];
List<Widget> nonNullable = nullableWidgets.whereType<Widget>().toList();
```

To answer your question:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget?>[
    // Widgets (some of them nullable)
  ].whereType<Widget>().toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Dart expert.

But it seems like the compiler does not respect your null safety checkup.

I suggest creating a new `List<Widget>` and populate it with each item from `List<Widget?>` which is not null.