# How to convert a List<T?> to List<T> in null safe Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I have a dart list:

```
List<String?> vals;
```

I want to remove any null values and convert it to a `List<String>`.
I've tried:

```
List<String> removeNulls(List<String?> list) {
  return list.where((c) => c != null).toList() as List<String>;
}
```

At run time I'm getting the following error:

```
List<String?>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>?'
```

What is the correct way to resolve this?

Comment: The package `collection`, provides an extension to do that: [whereNotNull()](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableNullableExtension/whereNotNull.html)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- Ideally you'd start with a `List<String>` in the first place.  If you're building your list like:

  ```dart
  String? s = maybeNullString();
  var list = <String?>[
    'foo',
    'bar',
    someCondition ? 'baz' : null,
    s,
  ];
  ```

  then you instead can use collection-`if` to avoid inserting `null` elements:

  ```dart
  String? s = maybeNullString();
  var list = <String?>[
    'foo',
    'bar',
    if (someCondition) 'baz',
    if (s != null) s,
  ];
  ```
- Dart 3 adds a [`nonNulls`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/NullableIterableExtensions/nonNulls.html) extension to filter out `null`s:

  ```dart
  var list = <String?>['foo', 'bar', null, 'baz', null];
  var withoutNulls = list.nonNulls.toList();
  ```
- Prior to Dart 3, an easy way to filter out `null` values from an `Iterable<T?>` *and* get an `Iterable<T>` result is to use `.whereType<T>()`.  For example:

  ```dart
  var list = <String?>['foo', 'bar', null, 'baz', null];
  var withoutNulls = list.whereType<String>().toList();
  ```
- Another approach is to use collection-`for` with collection-`if`:

  ```dart
  var list = <String?>['foo', 'bar', null, 'baz', null];
  var withoutNulls = <String>[
    for (var s in list)
      if (s != null) s
  ];
  ```
- Finally, if you already know that your `List` doesn't contain any `null` elements but just need to cast the elements to a non-nullable type, other options are to use [`List.from`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/List.from.html):

  ```dart
  var list = <String?>['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  var withoutNulls = List<String>.from(list);
  ```

  or if you don't want to create a new `List`, [`Iterable.cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/cast.html):

  ```dart
  var list = <String?>['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
  var withoutNulls = list.cast<String>();
  ```

Comment: So there is no way to cast the string without recreating it. My code removed the nulls, it was the cast that was the core issue.

Comment: @BrettSutton I had forgotten about `Iterable.cast`/`List.cast`, which wouldn't need to create a new `List`.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- **Without creating a new `List`**

  ```dart
  void main() {
    List<String?> list = ['a', null, 'b', 'c', null];
    list.removeWhere((e) => e == null); // <-- This is all you need.
    print(list); // [a, b, c]
  }
  ```
- **Creating a new `List`**

  First create a method, `filter` for example:

  ```dart
  List<String> filter(List<String?> input) {
    input.removeWhere((e) => e == null);
    return List<String>.from(input);
  }
  ```

  You can now use it:

  ```
  void main() {
    List<String?> list = ['a', null, 'b', 'c', null];
    List<String> filteredList = filter(list); // New list
    print(filteredList); // [a, b, c]
  }
  ```

To use `retainWhere`, replace the predicate in `removeWhere` with `(e) => e != null`

Comment: the without creating a new list doesn't meet the requirements as you don't end up with a List<String>. It may not contain any null items but the list is still the wrong type.

Comment: @BrettSutton If you want `List<String>` from a `List<String?` you'll have to create a new list and my second code does that.