# How to convert a list of numbers in a String to a list of int in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

After reading a line from a file, I have the following String:

```
"[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

What is the best way to convert this String back to `List<int>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just base on following steps:

1. remove the '[]'
2. splint to List of String
3. turn it to a int List

Sth like this:

```
  List<int> list =
  value.replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '')
.split(',')
.map<int>((e) {
return int.tryParse(e); //use tryParse if you are not confirm all content is int or require other handling can also apply it here
  }).toList();
```

**Update:**

You can also do this with the `json.decode()` as @pskink suggested if you confirm all content is int type, but you may need to cast to int in order to get the `List<int>` as default it will returns `List<dynamic>` type.

eg.

```
List<int> list = json.decode(value).cast<int>();
```

Comment: With the introduction of null-safety, this code gives an error, as the result of `tryParse` cannot be added to `List<int>`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896648/how-to-convert-a-listt-to-listt-in-null-safe-dart for an explanation of how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert String list to int list by another alternate method.

```
void main() {
List<String> stringList= ['1','2','3','4'];
List<int> intList = [];
stringList.map((e){
var intValue = int.tryParse(e);
intList.add(intValue!);
print(intList);
});
print(a);
}
```

Or by using for in loop

```
void main() {
List<String> stringList= ['1','2','3','4'];
List<int> intList = [];
for (var i in stringList){
int? value = int.tryParse(i);
intList.add(value!);
print(intList);
 }
}
```

Comment: Using `tryParse` is good, but then insisting it is non-null in `value!` is not. See my comment on the first answer.