# Flutter: How to filtrate data from `Stream<Foo?>` to `Stream<Foo>`

Tags: flutter, plugins, stream

I need to create a new `Stream<Foo>` from EventChannel in my plugin, I try to do it like this, but i had `Stream<Foo?>`, what I mast to do for filtred all null values and return as `Stream<Foo>`

```
  Stream<Foo> get getStream {
    return _eventChannel
        .receiveBroadcastStream()
        .map<Foo?>((dynamic status) {
      assert(
      status is int,
      'status should be int, but it is ${status.runtimeType}',
      );
      if (status is int) {
        return FooStatus.valueOf(status); // can be null
      }
    }).helpMeFiltredLikeThis<Foo>((Foo? value) => value != null); // how i can do some like this
  }
```

Comment: [For `Iterable`s, the typical approach would be to use `.whereType`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66896866/).  Alas, [`Stream` does not have a `.whereType` method](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34050).  See the linked GitHub issue for an example that combines `Stream.where()` and `Stream.cast()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cast` at the end like this:

```
final nonNullableStream = nullableStream.cast<Foo>();
```