# How to make a generic functions in List<T> to get a Non-Optional type in Dart - Null Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, extension-methods, null-safety

We are migrating our **Flutter** app into **null safety** and I've encountered a bunch of missing helpers in order to get rid easily of an **optional into a non-optional of the same type.**

To get you in the context, I would like to have a

`List<String?> optionalList = ['hi', 'hola', null];`

and similar to `compactMap()` in Swift, I would like to have a function that can convert any map into a map that excludes the null items and only return a list of non-optional items
ex:

```
final List<String> newNonOptionalList = optionalList.compactMap((item) => item.toUpperCase());
// newNonOptionalList = ['HI', 'HOLA']
```

I'm trying to make a helper for these kinds of cases, including many others I found valuable for **Dart**.

Does anyone have an idea of why it is not working, this is a little of what I've tried so far:

```
extension ListNullSafetyExtension<T> on List<T?>? {

Iterable<R> compactMap<R>(R Function(T element) convert) sync* {
  for (var element in this.removeNulls()) {
    if (element != null) yield convert(element);
  }
}

  List<T> removeNulls() {
    if (this == null) return [];
    this!.removeWhere((value) => (value == null));
    return List.from(this!).whereType<T>().toList();
  }
}
```

Even though this does remove the nulls and executes the map, it always returns the same optional type in the list, meaning it doesn't unwrap it and `removeNulls()` returns a `List<dynamic>` instead of a `List<the_type_I_used>`

I would really appreciate your help in understanding why these 2 functions never change their type since I can only find very basic generics posts of the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily collapse a `List<T?>` to a `List<T>` with `null` elements filtered out by using `Iterable.whereType<T>()`:

```dart
List<String?> optionalList = ['hi', 'hola', null];
List<String> newNonOptionalList = optionalList.whereType<String>().toList();
```

If you really want your own extension method (even though it doesn't add much):

```dart
extension IterableNullSafetyExtension<T> on Iterable<T?>? {
  Iterable<T> removeNulls() => this?.whereType<T>() ?? [];
}
```

Additionally, one thing wrong with your attempted implementation is that `ListNullSafetyExtension<T>` is already generic and parameterized on `T`.  When you later try to add an extension method:

```dart
List<T> removeNulls<T>() {
```

That extra `<T>` at the end makes `removeNulls` generic *again*, using a `T` that's independent of the `T` from `ListNullSafetyExtension`.  Don't do that.

Also see: [How to convert a List<String?> to List in null safe Dart?
Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66896648/)

Comment: This is the winning answer for sure! I really appreciate and I was totally doing a double generic! I still have a question, for the `compactMap` since it keeps being dynamic, `removeNulls` already works all right and I'm gonna update my answer for that one. But in your knowledge then why is it that even if I cast it with `whereType` in compactMap it still returns the a List<dynamic> ?

Comment: @KeylinWu Your `compactMap` implementation as originally written won't work because you made `ListNullSafetyExtension` also parameterized on `R`, but there's nothing for the extension to infer `R` from.  In that case, you want `extension ListNullSafetyExtension<T> on List<T?>?` and to make the `compactMap` method generic on `R`.

Comment: @jamesdelin So I tried what you just said:

`extension ListNullSafetyExtension<T> on List<T?>? {
  List<R> compactMap<R>(R Function(T element) convert) {
    return this != null ?
    this.removeNulls().map((e) => convert(e)).whereType<R>().toList() : [];
  }...`
but it is returning List<dynamic> still, am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
final List<String> newNonOptionalList = optionalList.compactMap((item) => item.toUpperCase());
```

to this

```
final List<String> newNonOptionalList = optionalList.compactMap((item) => item.toUpperCase()).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other languages have such an option, named compactMap()

Dart realization can be:

```
extension CompactMap<T> on Iterable<T?> {
  Iterable<T> compactMap<E>([E? Function(T?)? transform]) =>
      map(transform ?? (e) => e).where((e) => e != null).cast();
}
```