# How to use if statement in a List.map() in a children Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, widget

Example, I have a Wrap widget, and in children I have some code like:

```
           listTask.map((e) {
                  if (e.day!.contains(value))
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                    );
                }).toList()
```

I want it return Padding whenever it pass if statement, but it get error `The argument type 'List<Padding?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'`. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your callback to `List.map` does not explicitly return anything if the `if` condition fails, so the callback implicitly returns `null`, and you end up with a `List<Padding?>` instead of a `List<Padding>`. `List.map` creates a 1:1 mapping from input elements to output elements.

Either filter out the `null` elements afterward or use collection-`for` with collection-`if`:

```dart
  [for (var e in listTask)
    if (e.day!.contains(value))
      Padding(...),
  ]
```

Also see: [How to convert a List<T?> to List in null safe Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66896648/)

Comment: Yeah I realize that I dont have else statement, and your answer is great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

listTask.map((e) {

```
                return (e.day!.contains(value)) ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
                    height: 20,
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                ):Container();
            }).toList()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).